# JS: Object Array accessible in For loop, not out side

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, undefined

I'm making a Monopoly game from scratch, using JS, jQuery and AJAX and so on.

Having a frustrating issue.
I have defined a property object, and a property library array (both, outside of functions)....

```
var propLib = new Array();

var property = {
    position: 0,
    name: "",
    price: 0,
    rent: 0,
    ppHouse:0,
    mortage: 0,
    owner: "",
    priceWithHouse:[0,0,0,0,0],
};
```

Next, I populate the array with information from other arrays:

```
function popArray(){

                //Populate Property Library with Names off Board
                for(var i=0;i <= strPropNames.length;i++){
                    propLib.push(property);
                    propLib[i].position = i;
                    propLib[i].name = strPropNames[i];
                    propLib[i].price = intPropPrice[i];
                    propLib[i].mortage = (intPropPrice[i]/2);

                    alert(propLib[i].name + "Pos: "+ propLib[i].position+" "+propLib[i].price)
                }


    }
```

Notice: that alert, works fine, as soon as I try the same alert using a constant or another variable outside of this for loop, it returns as undefined.

So far I have tried declaring the variables without the "var" prefix as I read that may be more "global", to no avail.

**Answer being what insert_name_here advised:**

I was rewriting the same object each loop iteration, so the answer looks like so...

```
var newObject = jQuery.extend(true, {}, property);

                propLib.push(newObject);
```

Comment: Can you also post the data of strPropNames? It might happen that it doesn't have any values and strPropNames.length might return 0;

Comment: @Roman what is strPropNames

Comment: it is an array of the property names on the board, and as I said, the alert at the end of each iteration of the for loop works, so the string is being assigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems that I can see here.

First, the condition of the `for` loop, `i <= strPropNames.length` is wrong. It should be `i < strPropNames.length`, or else it'll iterate one too many times.

Second, you are pushing the same object (`property`) each time, without cloning it.

In JavaScript, a variable holding an object is actually just holding the reference to that object. When you push multiple copies of this variable onto an array, it's not copying the object; it's just copying the reference, meaning that whichever element of the array you're modifying, you're still modifying the same object.

So each time you're supposed to be modifying a "specific property", you're actually modifying the same one, since all the elements in `propLib` are referencing the same object. Since your `alert` executes at the end of each loop, it appears to be working fine, whereas in reality the data that the `alert` shows is overwritten in the next iteration.

Here's a corrected version:

```
function popArray(){

                //Populate Property Library with Names off Board
                for(var i=0;i < strPropNames.length;i++){
                    propLib.push({
                        position: 0,
                        name: "",
                        price: 0,
                        rent: 0,
                        ppHouse:0,
                        mortage: 0,
                        owner: "",
                        priceWithHouse:[0,0,0,0,0],
                    });
                    propLib[i].position = i;
                    propLib[i].name = strPropNames[i];
                    propLib[i].price = intPropPrice[i];
                    propLib[i].mortage = (intPropPrice[i]/2);

                    alert(propLib[i].name + "Pos: "+ propLib[i].position+" "+propLib[i].price)
                }


    }
```

Alternatively, you could keep your `property` template and clone it on each iteration (e.g. with `jQuery.extend`: `jQuery.extend(true, {}, property)`)

Comment: Yes on the <,
But as far as cloning the property, can you please explain?

Comment: Thanks to your mention of cloning I freaking got it like this:

var newObject = jQuery.extend(true, {}, property);
    
    propLib.push(newObject);

Comment: @RomanElizen I edited my answer with a more complete explanation.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhh, I see, would using the jQuery.extend pose any problems?

Comment: Thank you kindly for you help!

Comment: @RomanElizen No, using `jQuery.extend` should work fine here, as long as you use a deep copy (i.e. use `true` as the first argument, like you did).